# Table Row Banding by Section

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table that looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.band tr.highlight').next('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transparent');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    padding: .5rem;
}

th:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

th:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}

tr.highlight {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.band tr:nth-child(even):not(.highlight) td {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="band">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>heading 1</th>
    <th>heading 2</th>
    <th>heading 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td colspan="3">section 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td colspan="3">section 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The issue is that I would like the first row of each section to be transparent. Then alternate color/transparent for the remaining rows in the section.  I added a "transparent" class to the row 's after the section row, but I am not sure how to start a loop or the like on the remaining rows.  How can I add to the script (css solutions are great too) to handle the remaining rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution, I first added the `transparent` class to the first row after `highlight` class, then use the `nextUntil` method to loop through the next rows until another highlight, I added the class `gray` for the other rows, and this is the demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.band tr.highlight').next('tr').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transparent');
    var i = 1;
    $(this).nextUntil('.highlight').each(function() {
      if (i % 2 === 0) {
        $(this).addClass('transparent');
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('gray');
      }
      i++;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    padding: .5rem;
}

th:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: darkgray;
}

th:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}

tr.highlight {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.band tr:nth-child(even):not(.highlight), .band tr.gray{
    background-color: gray;
}

.band tr.transparent {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="band">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>heading 1</th>
    <th>heading 2</th>
    <th>heading 3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td colspan="3">section 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="highlight">
    <td colspan="3">section 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>info 1</td>
    <td>info 2</td>
    <td>info 3</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `nextUntil` was it, perfect, thank you.